# C - How to verify root CA on embedded devices (without openssl)

Tags: c, ssl

I am developing a platform independent application in C. The application need to communicate via secure websocket (TLS). Most SSL/TLS libraries provide a method to verify the certificate chain up to the root certificate. For this I need the root CA. But I do not want to store the root CA fix, because I want to have the opportunity to use other root CAs. Windows has a certificate store maintained by the operating system.

How can this be solved for the various Linux distributions? Some have not stored any root CAs. How do other platform-independent software components solve this?

Comment: I believe it is usual practice to always include at least one root certificate?

Comment: The Linux equivalent of the Windows certificate store is just certificate files stored under `/etc/ssl/certs`. They *do* store the root CAs in here (if they want to be able to perform any meaningful SSL at least).

Comment: *"But I do not want to store the root CA fix."* - does this mean that it is not acceptable to have the root CA in some file on the system? Or not as a fixed string in the application? Where do you want the root CA to retrieve from (in a secure way!) if you don't want to store it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question my self:

Mozilla has a list of trusted root certs public available here:
https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/raw-file/default/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt

There is a [online service](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) which extracts this data into a singe cacert.pem file.

The cacert.pem file can be included in the application for verifing certificates. Attention: This list has to be updated frequently!